# Virtual server EC2 recebe requisições mas não consegue acessar outro host

Tags: apache, servidor, conexão, amazon-aws

Tenho uma máquina virtual no Amazon AWS com Ubuntu onde eu mesmo instalei o Apache2, o PHP5 e o MySql.
Estava tudo rodando bem, bem configurado, meu site funcionando muito bem nele.

Até que de repente a máquina virtual parou de acessar outros hosts. Isso acontece para qualquer requisição.
Descobri isso quando um script PHP passou a dar erro de *connection timed out* ao usar a função `file_get_contents()`.

```
<?php echo file_get_contents('http://example.com'); ?>
```

Fui para a linha de comando do servidor, via SSH, e tentei dar um ping num host externo `ping google.com` e nada.
Tentei usar o `apt-get` para atualizar o sistema `apt-get update` e também não conecta.

Ou seja, o meu server EC2 não está conectando a nada externo.

O engraçado é que se eu tento acessar o site, o server recebe normalmente a requisição e devolve o site pro navegador. Ou seja, a conexão com a internet está existindo.

Outo detalhe é que, esse acesso ao `file_get_contents()` do PHP que estou tentando fazer é também no mesmo site, não num site externo, e ainda assim da *timed out*.

Aqui o resultado do comando `netstat -lnp`:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      957/sshd        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1098/mysqld     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      957/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      1145/apache2    
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1145/apache2    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           560/dhclient    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:18032           0.0.0.0:*                           560/dhclient    
udp6       0      0 :::60689                :::*                                560/dhclient    
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name    Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8236     785/dbus-daemon     /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     6500     1/init              @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8549     965/acpid           /var/run/acpid.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     6797     324/systemd-udevd   /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8919     1098/mysqld         /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Aqui o resultado do comendo `iptables -L`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

O que pode estar acontecendo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pra quem teve o mesmo problema como eu, fui a fundo até descobrir que o nameserver estava setado para o ip da amazon.

Então editei o `/etc/resolv.conf`
e coloquei os nameservers do google

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

e funcionou.
Espero que isso ajude alguém.